# Pycharm type hinting silly message: Expected type 'X' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'X' instead

Tags: pycharm, type-hinting

To reproduce:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Base:
    pass


class Derived:
    pass


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Base)


class BaseWriter(Generic[T]):
    def write(self, obj: T):
        pass


class DerivedWriter(BaseWriter[Derived]):
    pass


writer = DerivedWriter()
derived = Derived()
writer.write(derived)
```

The last line gets annotated by PyCharm as a type error

> Expected Type 'Derived' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'Derived' instead.

Am I using `TypeVar` incorrectly, or is this a bug in the type hinter?

Comment: Since `T` is bound to `Base`, shouldn't `Derive` subclass `Base`? Maybe just a typo in your exemple.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the concept of inheritance explicit in your code. Then you don't need to manually override the type checker. In the example below, a `Derived` **is-a** `Base` as well, so the `write` method in the last line gets precisely the type it expects (i. e. a `Base`) and PyCharm doesn't report any errors.

```
class Base:
    pass


class Derived(Base):
    pass


class BaseWriter:
    def write(self, obj: Base):
        pass


class DerivedWriter(BaseWriter):
    pass


writer = DerivedWriter()
derived = Derived()
writer.write(derived)
```

You probably don't even need different `Writer`s here, but that depends on the actual problem at hand.